# OSGI Bundles references not resolved

Tags: java-8, migration, osgi, upgrade, osgi-bundle

My team is maintaining a software that's built on Eclipse 3.8.2 with Java 1.7. Since we're trying to add a feature that requires Java 1.8 I've been tasked with upgrading our whole environment to Java 1.8 and in the process also upgrade to a newer version of Eclipse. So what I did is copy the workspace, opened it in Eclipse  4.9.0 and adressed all errors Eclipse threw at me. Among other things we're using OSGi and I'm having trouble launching our application in the new environment.
To be honest I'm not really experienced with OSGi. I've tried searching for the errors I'm getting, but I haven't found much useful material on the issue.

Anyway, when I'm launching the application I get a bunch of errors from OSGi thta bundle references are not resolved. I'm not sure which manifest requires those bundles, and how I have to include those. I have triple checked, that the run configuration has all the plugins, that the old and working version of the software has, so that doesn't seem to be it.

The trace I'm getting is:

```
!SESSION 2019-03-12 11:13:16.942 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.8.0_202
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_AT
Framework arguments:  -product at.jku.mevss.product.server
Command-line arguments:  -product at.jku.mevss.product.server -data D:\Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/../RCPClients/MCC -dev file:D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/(S1) - Monitoring Server Console + Services/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.ase.ulm/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.ase.ulm 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.lib/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.lib 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.product/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.product 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.ui/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.ui 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.processor.core/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.processor.core 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.impls/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.impls 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.checking.service.core/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.checking.service.core 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.eventpublisher.core/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.eventpublisher.core 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Eclipse Workspace for Java 8/at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.682
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
.
.
.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.checking.lib 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.714
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.core_0.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.checking.lib 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.714
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle at.jku.mevss.checking.service.core_0.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 at.jku.mevss.checking.lib 2 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.714
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-03-12 11:13:17.729
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "at.jku.mevss.server" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
An error has occurred. See the log file
D:\Eclipse Workspace for Java 8\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\(S1) - Monitoring Server Console + Services\1552385597136.log.
```

I removed a bunch of lines, since it was taking too much space.
Did I make a mistake when migrating to the new Eclipse? Did I forget to modify some manifest files? Could there be some settings that need to be changed for the new Java/Eclipse version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running on Java 8? One of the loud and clear requirements that is missing is support for the Java 1.8 execution environment.

Comment: A first mistake I seem to have identified is, that I was having the Target platform to the old eclipse installation, which does not support Java 8. I've now switched the target platform to the new Eclipse 4.9.0 and I'm now dealing with new problems related to SWT jars

Comment: But it seems to run on Java 7? Normally Eclipse automatically creates a capability for osgi.ee 1.8 when running on Java 8.

Comment: It says java.version=1.8.0_202- it must be running on java 8
I suppose you're using an old eclipse version not supporting Java 8 yet. Make sure you're on Luna or newer.
Open your org.eclipse.osgi.jar and look if it defines JavaSE-1.8.profile.